# Validation attributes

Tags: c#, validation, custom-attributes

I have an abstract class, which inherits a property from some interface. So it is impossible to validate the property backing field. So do you have any idea on how to implement custom attributes to validate properties?

You got abstract class Collaborator,

```
public abstract class Collaborator
{
}
```

Then you inherit it from some interfaces:

```
interface IPersonInformation
{
    String FirstName { get; set; }
    String LastName { get; set; }
}
interface IRecruitmentInformation
{
    DateTime RecruitmentDate { get; set; }
}
///
public abstract class Collaborator : IPersonInformation, IRecruitmentInformation
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecruitmentDate { get; set; } 
}
```

So you cannot validate properties in `Collaborator` class using their backing field - they are automatic. 
So is there a way to use attributes on the properties to validate name?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you provide sample code?

Comment: You do not have to use auto-implemented properties. Anyway you can use validation attributes (PostSharp, ValidationManager).

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Collaborator : IPersonInformation, IRecruitmentInformation
{
    private string firstName;
    public String FirstName
    { 
        get { return firstName; }
        set 
        {

            //validation code

            this.firstName = value;
        }
    }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecruitmentDate { get; set; } 
}
```

Should work fine as a way of implementing your interfaces.  I cannot think of a better way of achieving this using attributes.